# Get raw POST data from Firebase Function/Express/Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, http-post, application-xml

Using a Firebase Function to server POST requests. I need it to deal with `application/xml` data. But all I get back from `req.body` is an empty object `{}` as [Firebase Functions appears to only support certain data payloads](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request):

- `application/json`
- `application/octet-stream`
- `text/plain`
- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

So how can I get this work? I know Firebase Functions use Express underneath. Is there a way to get access to the raw POST data?